# how to show 2 different active qt application on two different surfaces in a single screen for imx6 board

Tags: qt, qml

how to show 2 different active qt application on two different surfaces in a single screen for imx6 board?

[EDIT]
Suppose there is two application.Mediaplayer and phone app.when mediaplayer will be running ,if anyone tries to call ,a pop up will show on top of mediaplayer to accept or reject.So,there will be 2 separate surface in a single screen and on accepting the app will change to phone app screen and on reject it will be there in the player screen.

[EDIT]
Both application are individual i.e media player for songs and phone for calling.How it is possible to combine in single app because in my case if incoming call is there then only pop will appear on top of mediaplayer and on accept it will go to phone screen.If you can give any logic for solution then it will be better for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please try describe the problem more. It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Suppose there is two application.Mediaplayer and phone app.when mediaplayer will be running ,if anyone tries to call ,a pop up will show on top of mediaplayer to accept or reject.So,there will be 2 separate sufrace in a single screen and on accepting the app will change to phone app screen and on reject it will be there in the player screen.

Comment: how to achieve it?any suggesion?

Comment: Are the applications two individual projects or just seperate qml files?

Comment: two different project?

Comment: What a sense to make it in 2 separate application? Why not combine these 2 tasks in one app? I would do 2 forms and will bring up one of them depend on incoming event. I think StackView is perfect for that

Comment: Both application are individual i.e media player for songs and phone for calling.How it is possible to combine in single app because in my case if incoming call is there then only pop will appear on top of mediaplayer and on accept it will go to phone screen.If you can give any logic for solution then it will be better for me.

Comment: If comments ask for clarification it is always better to clarify the question instead of put the information in a comment.